# Margin on child element added to parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the H2 to appear half way down the DIV (i.e. so it appears vertically in the middle of the image) however, when I add a `margin-top` to the H2 it seems to add it to the DIV as well.

What's the problem and what's the solution?

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <style type="text/css" scoped>
            .container {
                background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/250/business/");
                background-repeat: no-repeat; 
            }
            h2 { margin-top: 200px;}
        </style>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The problem is that the margins are [collapsing](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/):

> Vertical margins on different elements that touch each other (thus
>   have no content, padding, or borders separating them) will collapse,
>   forming a single margin that is equal to the greater of the adjoining
>   margins. This does not happen on horizontal margins (left and right),
>   only vertical (top and bottom).

2. The best solution which is not a hack is to change `margin` to `padding` and reset the default h2 `margin-top`:

   ```
   h2 { padding-top: 200px; margin-top:0;}
   ```
3. If the padding is not suitable, there are some other possible solutions to prevent the default collapsing:

   - `.container {border: 1px solid transparent}`
   - `.container {padding: 1px}`
   - `h2 {display: inline-block;}`
4. You say you wish to:

> to get the H2 to appear half way down the DIV

It might be that a better to use percent to support different container sizes. Consider doing something like this:

```css
.container {
   background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/250/business/");
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   height:250px;
   position:relative;
}

.go-down { 
   top:50%; 
   position:absolute;
}
            
.go-down h2 {
   margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="go-down">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```